# Designing a simple oop game class hierarchy

Tags: oop

I'm trying to make a Battleship game (see wikipedia:Battleship_(game)).

I have a `Player` class, a `Grid` class and a `Ship` class.

There's a Grid for each Player and each player has a set of Ships that live on the Grid.

How do I know whether to make the set of Ships members of the Player or the Grid?

At the start of the game the Players have to place their Ships on the Grid. I have a method that asks the Player where to place their Ships. How do I know in what class that method should be placed? If it's in Player but the set of Ships are in Grid then I'll have to get a reference to the set of Ships from the Grid. And then do I want Grid::PlaceShip(Ship) or Ship::Place(x, y)?

Is there a methodology for this? I've tried Class-Responsibilities-Collaborators but it's not giving me the answers to let me start coding. I'd rather learn how to find the answers myself than be given them for this specific example.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `Game` concept? Behavior almost never goes on the entity representing the initiator of all behaviors, like `Player`, `User`, etc. or all behavior would go on those entities. Perhaps `game.placeInitialShipsFor(player, shipLocations)` ?

Comment: I do have a Game class, I was trying to simplify to the classes I thought were involved. I could end up adding everything to the Game class and I've read that's a mistake. The game initiates the behaviour, the player is responsible for placing ships, the ships are responsible for being placed, it depends how you think about it and that confuses me.

Comment: Who's responsible for maintaining the integrity of the data? E.g. Only the game knows who's player turn it is and who already made it's initial placements. The classes like `Grid` and `Player` will still be involved if the high level function is placed on the `Game` object.

Comment: Ships being responsible "for being placed" isn't a concept that makes a ton of sense, imo. I'd expect ships to know their total/remaining health, and not much else, in a game of battle ship. This is a pretty opinionated question, in general, and there's going to be no single methodology that's an adequate answer to the general question of "how do I design classes for X".

Comment: Each Player has their own Grid, putting placeInitialShipsFor in Game, where there is no reference to Grid, seems very confusing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kinda depends on the surrounding code, but my instinct is that Ship should be part of Grid. There's a lot of overlap between the information represented by Grid and Ship that doesn't really concern the player: specific grid locations, legal guesses, etc. If you made Ship a part of Player, you'd still have to link the two directly, so that the Grid knows when a ship gets hit or not. There's little point in having a Grid if it doesn't even know where the Ships are.

There's no real hard and fast answer to the question: how do I build an object model? I try to imagine what functions/methods/subroutines I'll probably have to write, regardless of the object model. If the same concepts start popping up in the same set of functions, then they should be tied together in the object model.

It's also good to notice when you're representing the same information more than once in different parts of the code. For each task or resource, try to make sure that only one part of the code has responsibility for it. You may need to tweak your abstractions so that the responsible code can be used for slightly different things that all involve the same kind of work.

Your goal is simple code. If you start writing and the code gets more complicated as you go along (i.e. more difficult to understand), that's a sign that you need to rethink and refactor your model.